# jQuery.post .fail (.error) function acts sooner than it should and receive malformed json

Tags: jquery, wordpress, post, error-handling

I am writing an ajax formed comment posting for WordPress and here is what I have so far:

```
$.post('wp-comments-post.php', { data: Data, },
    function(result) {
        do_success_staff();
    })
    .fail(function(out) {
        do_fail_staff;
    });
```

When handling the `.fail(function(out)`, I am getting unexpected results. The wp-comments-post.php returns different answers according to the error, such as "please write your comment" if you had left it blank or "enter a valid email address" if the email address you entered is not in the right form. However, I am receiving the results like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>error</title>
<style type="text/css">
    your css goes here
</style>
</head>
<body id="error-page">
<p><strong>error</strong>: write your comment.</p></body>
</html>
```

Therefore, I tried to handle the error answers to be shown to user like this:

```
.fail(function(out) {
    var error_value = $(out).find("p");
        $("div#error").text(error_value);
    });
```

The problem is that it returns an internal server error (500 page) instead of the expected results. What do you think about this problem? I think that the error page is received before that it is parsed by the browser! Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: That isn't json, it's an ordinary javascript object. Look at it's `responseText` property. `console.log(out.responseText)`

Comment: Try `$("div#error").text(error_value.html());` because `error_value` is a json object, to get the content inside use `error_value.html()`

Comment: Also change to `var error_value = $(out).filter("p");`

Comment: i had already used them but no answer!

Comment: for all answers it sends out one "responseText" as "internal server error"; i need to tell the user what was his/her mistake.
his/her comment or email or ...

Comment: So, `out.responseText` gives you `internal server error`? That would indicate a php error, not a wp-comment error.

Comment: @KevinB - most of the time, that would indicate a server error, for instance Apache encountering an error, which of course could be triggered by PHP failing etc. but most of the time PHP errors will just return as strings.

Comment: @adeneo I guess the point i was making is it isn't the wp-comment error, it's something else. I narrowed it down to php unintentionally.

Comment: but i think that the WordPress itself uses the code witch i wrote as console.log.(out) to find out what to say to user as the result of occurred error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

many thanks to [Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) who solved my problem. the continue of this question and its answer are here at:

[do you know type of code this is and how to parse it with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772701/do-you-know-type-of-code-this-is-and-how-to-parse-it-with-jquery)